# SonarQube + Firefox localization

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I am having a localization problem when loading SonarQube 5.1.1 on Firefox.
The same problem does not happen on Google Chrome.
It does not happen only on my machine.

Even when I try to load the Sonar online demo, the same problem happen:
http://nemo.sonarqube.org/

**Wrong on Firefox**
 
[image: PROBLEMATIC ON FIREFOX]

**Right on Google Chrome**
[image: OK ON CHROME]

How can I fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same here: [SonarQube - No translations: NS_ERROR_DOM_QUOTA_REACHED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32560413/sonarqube-no-translations-ns-error-dom-quota-reached)

The cause of the problem is the localstorage.

1. Open JavaScript console (F12 -> Console)
2. Type `localStorage.clear();` -> Enter
3. Reload (F5)
4. In the console you can see `NS_ERROR_DOM_QUOTA_REACHED: Persistent storage maximum size reached`

The localstorage max quota in firefox is based on the main domain (for `nemo.sonarqube.org`-> `sonarqube.org`). But I have no idea why your localStorage for this domain should reach the limit. Maybe some other bug or the `localStorage.clear();` in the JavaScript console solves your issue...?

It's definitly a bug in SonaQube. They have to check the size limits of localStorage or use another caching mechanism.
Unfortunately I have not found where I can report the problem.

---

Edit: Now there is a JIRA ticket: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/JPzsLhtuziQ - https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7105