# SonarQube - No translations: NS_ERROR_DOM_QUOTA_REACHED

Tags: localization, internationalization, local-storage, sonarqube, translation

we are using SonarQube 5.1.2 on a domain like `sonarqube.companyname.com`.

Because of a firefox bug (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1064466) the local storage quota isn't based on the subdomain. As we are using many applications on domains with the suffix `.companyname.com` which also uses localStorage I got the following error in the JavaScript console:

```
NS_ERROR_DOM_QUOTA_REACHED: Persistent storage maximum size reached
```

And the result looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjH48.png

Is there anything I can do? Maybe a config setting to disable the localstorage translation caching?

Has anyone else the same problem?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31299247/sonarqube-firefox-localization

Comment: Can someone from SonarSource Team confirm this as a bug? Is there already any solution or workaround? Is there another way to contact SonarSource Team? I don't have the permission to create a bug ticket on https://jira.sonarsource.com, but on http://www.sonarqube.org/get-support/ I read "[...] You should consider posting a question on Stack Overflow [...] Our team is continuously following the 'sonarqube' tag [...]".